# Python Error, when i'm using ARIMA .. TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, time-series, typeerror, forecasting, arima

I use this formation of pandas dataframe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ltk.jpg)

And, my code is here.

```
# Execution logic goes here
dataframe1 = dataframe1.drop(['Column 6'],axis=1)
dataframe1 = dataframe1.drop(['TIME'],axis=1)    

data_idx = pd.date_range('2015-9-3', '2016-8-25', freq='D')      
dataframe1["idx"] = data_idx
dataframe1.set_index('idx', inplace=True)
del dataframe1.index.name
print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1)) 

temp = pd.DataFrame( dataframe1 ,index=data_idx)        
temp.update(dataframe1)



print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(temp))    

model = ARIMA(temp, order= (5,1,0))
arima_data = model.fit()    
return arima_data,code here
```

The error log is like this:

> model = ARIMA(temp, order= (5,1,0))
>   File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 965, in **new**
>   mod.**init**(endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)
>   File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 984, in **init**
>   self.data.ynames = 'D.' + self.endog_names
>   TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
>   Process returned with non-zero exit code 1

So, I want to use ARIMA.... but I cant find right solution... please help me.

Comment: Your time series `temp` needs to be univariate such as a pandas series and not a data frame with several columns. The exception is because there are several column_names in `temp`, so that `endog_names` is a list instead of a string.

Comment: @user333700 Thanks you. So, ARIMA cant use mutivariate dataframe??

Comment: @user333700 I have to find another way to use multivariate data for prediction ;(